# email Rendering issues with outlook web app

Tags: email, templates, outlook, rendering, outlook-web-app

When coding emails, i seem to be getting broken templates in the Outlook web app preview pane, however when i double click the email (email opens in new window) it renders fine.

The text within td's have alot of spacing between lines, images aren't vertical-aligning correctly amongst other issues.

Does anyone know what causes this and how it can be fixed? I did read on-line that the preview pane wraps the email in its own  and adds its own styling which affects the layout?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues it could be, but I'd start with putting this in your style tag:

```
#outlook a {padding:0;}
```

Also, are you using tables? Make sure your `<td>`'s at least 19px high.

For images, make sure you have `display:block;` and the padding and margin zero'd out.

```
<img alt="" src="" width="" height="" style="margin: 0; border: 0; padding: 0; display: block;">
```

Beyond that, post some example code as it is hard to figure out the exact cause of each issue without seeing it.